# Using Field name as select parameter in SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqldatasource

Is it possible to use a field name as a select parameter in an SQLDataSource?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection.ProviderName %>"      
SelectCommand="select * from sometable where @FieldKey = @FieldValue">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="FieldKey" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="FieldValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To be able to change the where condition based on a supplied field name

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hack(workaround) most time

```
protected void page_load(...)
{
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["FieldKey"] = field;
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["FieldName"] = name;
}
```

OR create two hidden fields, assign the values to those fields and then use

```
<asp:ControlParameter />
```

That is another hack

Answer (score 1):

### OPTION 1

If `FieldKey` and `FieldName` are taking from code behind I think you can easily set command as below.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = string.Format("select * from sometable where {0} = {1}",fieldKey ,fieldValue)
```

please validate input fields for SQL injection attacks.

### OPTION 2

Create stored procedure to accept two parameters key and value, you need to **build SQL query from those parameters and execute inside stored procedure**.

Then you can call it from datasource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbConnection.ProviderName %>"      
    SelectCommand="StoredProcedureName"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="FieldKey" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="FieldValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: That is the way I ended up going, however, I would rather a solution straight from the .aspx page.

Comment: @jax add another alternative way

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is using values from a control [like textbox, dropdown] then here is something

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FieldKey" PropertyName="Text"
         Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FieldName" PropertyName="Text"
         Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Assuming the values are stored in textboxes

Comment: No, the SQL is inside a class that extends UserControl, the property is in the code behind of this class